# How to remove duplicate data and calculate number by the same data’s field

Tags: python, django, database

I use python and django.

I want to  remove duplicate data by field ‘agent__id’ and 'account', and count the field 'agent__id' by the same data . My code is follow:

```
list(AgentPayLog.objects.values('agent__id', 'account').
                  distinct().values('agent__id').annotate(agent_count=Count(F('agent'))).
                  values('agent__id', 'agent_count'))
```

the data is following:

```
account_id  agent_id
30001       1 
30001       2
30001       2
```

the code print is following:

```
agent_id agent_count
1        1
2        2
```

I want the data is following:

```
agent_id agent_count
1        1
2        1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, we should use the attribute 'distinct' in object 'Count' , the source code of main method is following:

```
class Count(Aggregate):

def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, **extra):
    if expression == '*':
        expression = Star()
    super(Count, self).__init__(
        expression, distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '', output_field=IntegerField(), **extra)
```

So, we can use the `Count('field', distinct=True)`, the right code is following:

```
list(AgentPayLog.objects.filter(bill__status=DEAL_STATUS_PAID).distinct().values('agent__id').
                  annotate(agent_count=Count(F('account_id'), distinct=True)).
                  values('agent__id', 'agent_count'))
```